# Tensorflow in_top_kv

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes, recurrent-neural-network, tensor

Hi there i'm trying to build a simple rnn with 11 inputs and 2 outputs 
`X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,n_steps,n_inputs])
y=tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None,n_steps,n_outputs])`

I know the rnn excepts an input in the shape of [batch_size,n_steps,n_inputs] so that's why i have shaped my placeholders like this

However when i run the code i get an error

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'in_top_k/InTopKV2' (op: 'InTopKV2') with input shapes: [1,270,2], [1,270,2], [].

The error seems to originate here : `correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits,tf.reshape(y,[1,n_steps,n_outputs]),1)`

I have tried reshaping the logits, squeezing the logits, expanding the y dimensions, but nothing seems to work.

One difference that i have noticed is that when i squeeze the logits with

```
tf.squeeze(logits)
```

The error now says

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 3

That is the only 'progress' that i have been able to make, any help would be appreciated.

p.s go easy on me this is my first question ever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reshape the inputs as 2D tensors, then you can reshape the result back to the desired shape:

```
logits_res = tf.reshape(logits, (-1, n_outputs))
y_res = tf.reshape(y, (-1, n_outputs))
correct_res = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits_res, y_res, 1)
correct = tf.reshape(correct_res, (-1, n_steps))
```

Comment: Hey @jdehesa i tried your code and, i'm still getting the error but this time instead of Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 i am now getting  Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2, what do you suggest i should do next

Comment: Ok being the tinkerer that i am this is the very inefficient fix that is going to make somebody at google laugh, at the reshaping part of @jdehesa code i added  tf.squeeze in between 'logits_res = tf.reshape(logits, (-1, n_outputs))
logits_res = tf.squeeze(logits_res)
y_res = tf.reshape(y, (-1,n_outputs))
y_res = tf.squeeze(y_res)'

Comment: @jetychill Oh my bad, I didn't read everything right. But I'm not sure everything is right here. In `in_top_k` the second parameter is an integer indicating the id of the class, so the `y` placeholder should have shape `(batch_size, n_steps)` (then would need to be resized). And in any case, I'm not sure why you would use `in_top_k` if you have just two classes... In fact, if you have only two classes usually you can have a single output (e.g. 0 is the first class and 1 is the second class).

Comment: Tensorflow makes me cry in bed at night that's all I'm gonna say. and thanks for the help

Comment: @jetychill Haha well just give it a little time, hopefully it'll grow on you. Do not hesitate to keep asking questions (here or on a new post) if you keep having trouble.

Comment: Ok just so everybody know i ended up ditching in_top_kv entirely and simply using correct = y and calculating accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct,tf.float32)) i still have issues with reshaping on the validation set but it should be an easy fix, also just out of curiosity does the logit plug into the outputs or in the states of tf.nn.dynamic_rnn

Comment: @jetychill Glad you got it to work. `logits` should surely be the output of the RNN, not the state. Do not feel that you have to accept this answer to resolve the question, you can also post your own answer and accept it if you feel that will make it clearer.